# adding labels with Terraform in existing Google Project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, label

I'm trying to set new labels on a google project that is already created with Terraform. I find documentation on how to do it when you create the project but no when the project already exist.

If I try with "resource", it made (of course) a 403 error because he's trying to create another project. With "data" it raise an error because labels are computed attributes.

Does it possible, or I need to set these labels at the project creation ?

Comment: Are you trying to set the labels in the same terraform state that created these resources? Because it seems you are trying to update something that wasn't created by your tf.

Comment: This project wasn't created by tf indeed.

Comment: If you want to manage it via terraform you need to first import these resources to terraform state. https://www.terraform.io/language/state/import -- after that, you will be able to change its labels and everything

Comment: Thanks @JuanFontes it works !
(I still have some lack on Terraform)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a project this way

```
resource "google_project" "my_project" {
  name       = "My Project"
  project_id = "xxxxxx"
  org_id     = "xxxxxxxxx"
  labels     = {
    "department" = "eng",
    "depart" = "account",
  }
```

updated label and did a terraform apply, it worked for me

```
resource "google_project" "my_project" {
  name       = "My Project"
  project_id = "xxxxx"
  org_id     = "xxxxxxxxx"
  labels     = {
    "department" = "eng",
    "depart" = "account",
    "school" = "chemistry"
  }
```